# Finding the id from the highest date when multiple dates are present

Tags: sql, date, inner-join, max, multiple-tables

When I run this query I get:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r2.ApplicationBK,
                max(r2.DatumApplication) maxdatum,
                p.Name
FROM FCT_Recruitment r2,
     DIM_WervingsProject wp,
     DIM_Persoon p
WHERE r2.WervingsProjectID = wp.WervingsProjectID
  AND r2.PersoonID=p.PersoonID
GROUP BY ApplicationBK,
         p.name
```

The names are standing in TALBLE DIM_PERSOON P  
The "ApplicationBK" are standing in DIM_Wervingsproject 
and all the dates (DatumAppliocation) are standing in FCT_Recruitment

```
BK  -  Date - Name 
012    20-03-1999  - name1 
023    21-03-1999  - name1 
033    22-03-1999  - name1 
112    20-03-1990  - name2 
123    20-03-1999  - name2 
133    20-03-1990  - name2
```

But i need the highest date for each name.. So each name may only stand one time in the 'name-column' with the corresponding id (ApplicationBK) and date. I don't need to rest.

When this didn't work I tried something else...

```
SELECT WervingsprojectBK,
       r.ApplicationBK,
       p.Name,
       count(*) number,upper(r.StatusWP) status,
                       upper(r.StatusApplication)statusdetail,
                       r.DateApplication 
FROM FCT_Recruitment AS r,
     DIM_WervingsProject wp,
     DIM_Persoon p
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT r2.ApplicationeBK,
                   max(r2.DateApplication) maxdatum
   FROM FCT_Recruitment r2,
        DIM_WervingsProject wp,
        DIM_Persoon p
   WHERE r2.WervingsProjectID=wp.WervingsProjectID
     AND r2.PersoonID=p.PersoonID
   GROUP BY ApplicationBK) AS r2 ON (r.ApplicationBK=r2.ApplicationBK
                                     AND r.DateApplication=r2.maxdatum)
GROUP BY WervingsprojectBK,
         r.ApplicationBK,
         p.Naam,
         r.StatusApplication,
         r.StatusWP
ORDER BY 5
```

but then i get these errors..:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 The multi-part identifier
>   "r.ApplicationBK" could not be bound. 
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State
>   1, Line 3
>   The multi-part identifier "r.DateApplication" could
>   not be bound.

Can you please help this newby.. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
select 
  r2.ApplicationBK, 
  r22.maxdatum, 
  p.Name
from FCT_Recruitment r2
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT WervingsProjectID, max(r2.DatumApplication) maxdatum
  FROM FCT_Recruitment
  GROUP BY WervingsProjectID
) AS r22  ON r2.WervingsProjectID = r22.WervingsProjectID
         AND r2.DatumApplication  = r22.maxdatum
INNER JOIN DIM_WervingsProject AS wp ON r2.WervingsProjectID = wp.WervingsProjectID
INNER JOIN DIM_Persoon         AS p  ON r2.PersoonID         = p.PersoonID;
```

Comment: Ok there are no errors but i still have several times the same name and I just need the name with the highest date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. And change column name:

```
SELECT max(r.AllDate),r.ProjectID,p.name 
FROM FCT_Recruitment r,DIM_Wervingsproject pr, DIM_PERSOON p 
where p.PID=r.PID and r.ProjectId=pr.ProjectID 
group by r.PID;
```